# Android, import external library to NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, import-libraries

i am making an Android Shapefile reader app on Android with the use of NDK. I want to use C++ to parse shape files. I found library "Shapefile C Library". Github: https://github.com/sw897/shapelib.

I am using Android studio and have no idea how to import it to my Android project so i could use functions described in: http://shapelib.maptools.org/shp_api.html

Any tips?

Comment: If you're using it in other C code, it just needs to be linked to your C code.  If you're using it from Java, you need to write a JNI wrapper in C code and matching Java functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, start hacking away at the Hello-JNI example from Google:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni

Use that as a test bed.

Then, create a Java Class with `public native` methods that let you interact with your library.  Something of a high level API, probably to pass a file name or buffer to SHPOpenLL and return a pointer to the ShapeFile context (`ShapeHandle`).  Looks like your library is written in C, so you should be able to write a similar interface to query the shapefile passing a (jint) c-style cast of your `ShapeHandle` pointer.

Next, you need to play around with `javah` to generate the header for your shapefile interface.  Once the header is generated, you can use it to implement your interface in a .cc file.  From there you will basically make Java calls to your C interface and it will return jobjects. (jint, jbool, jstring, etc...)

---

I'm looking at the ShapeLib that you want to use and while it's easy enough, there will be some gotchas.

- You will need to implement [SAHooks](https://github.com/sw897/shapelib/blob/master/shapefil.h#L282) for file I/O.  I suggest looking at [NVFile](https://github.com/PolygonTek/BlueshiftEngine/tree/master/Engine/Source/Dependencies/nvidia/nv_file) for an example how to  access APK files (or downloaded files). You will need to init it using activity.context.assetmanager.  Then use nv_file to wrap FRead/FSeek/etc...
- Passing info back to java is going to be tough.  Personally, I would build a Java class to hold the shape information and fill it out on the `C` side.  However, you might be tempted to query these parameters from the `SHPObject` one at a time.  Will be slow, but less error prone.

E.g.

```
// Java 
MyJavaShapeObject obj = new MyJavaShapeObject();
_c_retrieveShapeObj((jint)pShapeFile, obj);

// C
java_blah_blah_c_retrieveShapeObj(JNIEnv* env, jclass activity, jint theShapeFile, jobject theObj){
    ShapeHandle pShapeFileHandle = (ShapeHandle)theShapeFile; // c style conversion
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647646/how-to-use-the-jni-to-change-the-fields-of-a-java-class
    // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16613
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/36759159/7949696
}
```